# When should the selectize.js function selectize() be called?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I am trying to use selectize.js to populate a combo-box on a form in my application.

I am trying to follow the ["Rotten Tomatoes" model on the selectize web page.](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)  But I am a little puzzled about the timing of this call.  The author prefers to initialize the select with a little <script> immediately following the specification of the <select> in the html file, but I would rather keep all my script in a separate js file.

Anyway I do the following

```
function loadSelect() 
{
    var myAPI = "my/api/";
    var count = 0;
    console.log('in loadSelect()'); 

    $('#myselect').empty();
    $('#myselect').selectize({
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: 'name',
        options: [],
        create: true,
        load: function(query, callback) {
            console.log("loading data");
            if (!query.length) {
                console.log("no data loaded");
                return callback();
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: myAPI,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    q: query,
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("failure");
                    callback();
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log("success");
                    count = res.data.length;
                    callback(res.data);
                }
            });    
        }
    });
}
```

No matter when I call this loadSelect() function, whether it be from the `$(document).ready(function(){` or directly from the html page after the declaration of the select as the selectize author does, I find that the load() method never gets called.  Note the console.log statements.  The first one, `'in loadSelect()'` always fires but any logs inside the load() function never fire.

[Project documentation](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) describes the load callback as follows:

> Invoked when new options should be loaded from the server.

but this begs the question **when** **should** new options be loaded from the server.

**In any event, what can I do to insure that load callback fires?**

Answer (score 0):

add the option preload:true to the array of options passed to the selectize call.